# ruby sketchup scene serialization

Tags: json, ruby, serialization, sketchup

I am very new on Sketchup and ruby , I have worked with java and c# but this is the first time with ruby.

Now I have one problem, I need to serialize all scene in one json (scene hierarchy, object name, object material and position this for single object) how can I do this?

I have already done this for unity3D (c#) without a problem.

I tried this:

```
def main   
  avr_entities = Sketchup.active_model.entities # all objects

  ambiens_dictionary = {}
  ambiens_list = []

  avr_entities.each do |root|

    if root.is_a?(Sketchup::Group) || root.is_a?(Sketchup::ComponentInstance)
      if root.name == ""
        UI.messagebox("this is a group #{root.definition.name}")

        if root.entities.count > 0
          root.entities.each do |leaf|
            if leaf.is_a?(Sketchup::Group) || leaf.is_a?(Sketchup::ComponentInstance)
              UI.messagebox("this is a leaf #{leaf.definition.name}")
            end
          end
        end

      else
        # UI.messagebox("this is a leaf #{root.name}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `require 'json'; some_var.to_json`

Comment: There is no built in serialisation of SketchUp entities/models to JSON so you need to figure out your own method. For each subclass of `Sketchup::Entity` you need to determine what properties to export and how to represent them. How you do that is determined by the requirements of whatever will be using it.

Comment: hmm.. Is this question about how to recursively dig down into every child-instance of the model? Because I notice your code only traverse the root and first level.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [JSON library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

```
require 'json'
source = { a: [ { b: "hello" }, 1, "world" ], c: 'hi' }.to_json
source.to_json # => "{\"a\":[{\"b\":\"hello\"},1,\"world\"],\"c\":\"hi\"}"
```

Comment: ty but is not my problem , i need to get all object in hierarchy i am tring with recursive method

Comment: I'm not sure that you mean, it converts the entire data structure to JSON, I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Used the code below to answer a question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513218/create-a-plugin-that-puts-text-in-a-txt-file/71464146#71464146), but it might also work here.

The code can run outside of SketchUp for testing in the terminal. Just make sure to follow these steps...

Copy the code below and paste it on a ruby file (example: file.rb)
Run the script in terminal `ruby file.rb`.

The script will write data to JSON file and also read the content of JSON file.

The path to the JSON file is relative to the ruby file created in step one. If the script can't find the path it will create the JSON file for you.

```
module DeveloperName
  module PluginName
    require 'json'
    require 'fileutils'

    class Main
      def initialize
        path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
        @json = File.join(path, 'file.json')
        @content = { 'hello' => 'hello world' }.to_json
        json_create(@content)
        json_read(@json)
      end

      def json_create(content)
        File.open(@json, 'w') { |f| f.write(content) }
      end

      def json_read(json)
        if File.exist?(json)
          file = File.read(json)
          data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
          puts "Json content: #{data_hash}"
        else
          msg = 'JSON file not found'
          UI.messagebox(msg, MB_OK)
        end
      end
      # # #
    end
    DeveloperName::PluginName::Main.new
  end
end
```